Sandbox for Proposed Questions
The Sandbox works best if you sort posts by "active" (click here to do so).

Welcome to the Sandbox!
This "Sandbox" is a place where Worldbuilding.SE users can get feedback on prospective questions they wish to post. This is useful, because new and experienced users can have trouble writing a clear and fully specified question.

There is a much better chance of your question being well received if you post it in the Sandbox first.

If you're here to help mentor Sandbox questions (THANK YOU!), jump to the "Helping in the Sandbox" section.  If this sandbox has grown too full, jump to the "Maintenance" section.

Please don't vote on any of the proposed questions in the Sandbox. Votes don't mean anything here and you could inadvertently bias others who might help, or worse, make a new person feel like their question writing skills are hopeless. Or worse yet, much better than they are. If you think a question is good, leave a note of encouragement and a helpful tip. If you think a question is bad, leave a note of encouragement and offer your help to make it better!


Posting to the Sandbox
Please take the time to read through the Help Center > Asking pages. We know it's a lot to read, but those pages contain the rules our mentors are using to judge your proposed question.  If you have not taken the time to read through them, we ask that you do.  It would also be beneficial to read through our Meta posts about high concept questions, open-ended questions, and what "primarily opinion-based" means on a creative site like Worldbuilding.SE.
To post a question to the Sandbox:
Post an answer to this post with the content of your proposed question. You can create as many answers as you have proposed questions, but it is recommended that you only work on one question at a time. The content of the post should be as close as possible to the format you would use when asking on the main site. If you would like, you may add a section at the bottom explaining what parts of the proposed question you are most worried about (See the Sandbox FAQ for more information on suggested syntax).
Once you have posted your proposed question, users will be able to comment on it with feedback. You can then respond to their feedback with comments of your own, or make edits to your post to attempt to address their feedback (after editing, be sure to notify the user via a comment of your own, use @username in your comment to make this happen). The feedback/edit cycle can go on for as long as needed until either you are confident that your question is ready to be asked on the main site, or you've decided the question just won't work.

Please be patient.  While most sandbox reviews can be completed in a couple of days, some questions may require a week or more for review.

Finally, please ignore votes. We've asked mentors to not vote for Sandbox questions because questions change here too frequently.  Nevertheless, those index fingers hovering over left mouse buttons are trained to vote, so votes occasionally appear.  Please completely ignore votes that happen to appear for your proposed question.
When your question is ready

Post it to the main site.
Add a link to your main-site post to the bottom of the "Graduated Questions" list.  The list is the accepted answer to this post.
Edit your Sandbox post so that it only contains the title and a link to the main-site post.  Delete everything else.
Delete all of your comments.
Finally, delete your Sandbox post.  Users with enough rep can still see the post, but it will be moved automatically to the bottom of the answer list, making this Sandbox easier to use.

If you abandon your question
Occasionally a Sandbox question is abandoned.  While crafting the question, you may discover the answer.  Or you may realize that the question's basic premise can't be expressed within the rules of Worldbuilding.SE.  You may also simply forget that you have a question in the Sandbox.  If you decide to abandon the question:

Edit your Sandbox post so that it only contains the title and a notice (e.g., "Abandoned question.").  Delete everything else.
Delete all of your comments.
Finally, delete your Sandbox post.  Users with enough rep can still see the post, but it will be moved automatically to the bottom of the answer list, making this Sandbox easier to use.

Please be aware that questions without activity (edits to your question or comments left by you) for more than one month may be judged abandoned and removed.  We'll leave a comment or two to get your attention, but eventually, forgotten questions will be cleaned up and deleted.

Helping in the Sandbox
We are sincerely grateful for the many users who help mentor questions and new users here in the Sandbox.  Sharing your experience adds considerably to the quality and enjoyment of the site.  We invite you to help us by adhering to the following policies.
Keep the Sandbox clean. In order to keep the Sandbox clean users are encouraged to look out for questions that have not seen any activity in some time.

If you notice the OP has not edited his/her proposed question or left a comment in 2 or more weeks, please tap the OP on the shoulder with a comment (e.g., "Are you still working on this question?  This draft might be deleted if there is no further activity.")
If you notice the OP has not edited his/her proposed question or left a comment in more than a month, please flag the question for moderator attention (e.g., "This Sandbox question has been inactive for a month.").  Please do not take it upon yourself to delete the OP's question.

Delete your comments when they no longer apply. Please make it easy for others to see which comments are still relevant to the discussion by removing your obsolete comments. In addition you can ask a mod to purge comments under graduated posts or move them to chat under abandoned posts to make it easier for users that can see deleted posts to use the Sandbox.
Please do not vote on proposed questions. Questions in the Sandbox frequently change (it's why they're here) — and the moment they change your vote may no longer reflect your beliefs.  It's unreasonable to expect mentors to constantly watch Sandbox questions and there is no automatic way (indeed, there's no way at all…) to notify voters when a question is edited.  It is better to use comments.  If you feel the question should be downvoted, explain the problem in a comment.  If you feel the question is ready for the main site, say so in a comment.  The dates on the comments allow other people to judge the relevance of your statements.
Please do not answer questions here. We know it's tempting, but answering the question in a comment will clog the comments and may not even be relevant to the final form of the question. If you have an answer for the proposed question, simply wait for it to be posted to the main site, and answer it there.
Please do not edit a proposed question unless you have the OP's permission to do so.  The purpose of the Sandbox is two-fold: (a) to perfect a question and (b) to help users learn to craft good questions.  If you jump in and fix a question you've subverted (b).  Whenever possible, let the OP edit their proposed question.  Exception: If a question has been deleted but not properly cleaned up, help us out by editing the question to remove everything but the title.  Thanks!
See the Sandbox FAQ for more information on how to use the Sandbox.

Maintenance
This section is referred to when a new sandbox is created.  In order to make the Sandbox easier to use, a new Sandbox question will be posted when the old one becomes too full (between 75 and 100 sandbox questions).
Whomever creates the new page: be sure you want to be actively involved with the Sandbox, because until it gets replaced in the future, you'll be notified of every proposed question and every comment.
(A) Update this previous sandbox list:
The previous sandbox post should be locked as obsolete by a moderator and renamed to "Inactive Sandbox [Date]." Please add a link to the top of the old sandbox page to the new Sandbox.

Deactivating Sandbox 2022-2024
Inactive Sandbox 2019-2022
Inactive Sandbox 2018
Inactive Sandbox 2017-18
Inactive Sandbox 2014-2017

If there are active questions in the old Sandbox, leave a comment for the users indicating that the old sandbox is closing and they either need to wrap up (preferred) or re-post the question in the new Sandbox.
(B) Create the new Sandbox page
Create the new Sandbox page by clicking "Edit" on the previous page and copying the question contents to the new post. Use the following Meta tags: discussion, questions, sandbox.
(C) Update these links after the new Sandbox is created:

Help Center/on-topic (This requires the help of a moderator)
Sandbox FAQ (The Sandbox FAQ has two links to the currently active sandbox: one in the question proper and one in the answer the above link takes you to.)
The sort-by-active link at the top of the new Sandbox.
The current sandbox link in our "Welcome to Worldbuilding.SE!" page.
Update the worldbuilding-process Wiki page to point to the new Sandbox page.

(D) Create the "Graduated Question List" answer and mark it a "Community Wiki."

Copy the prologue to the Graduated Question List from the previous Sandbox into the new List.
Update the first graduated question link to point to the current sandbox.
Mark the answer a Community Wiki.
Return in two days to accept the question (green check mark).


Site Help is now linked.

Ping me when you're ready for the old sandbox to be closed.

Thanks @MontyWild

Graduated Questions List
In accordance with Sandbox policy, answers containing graduated questions will be deleted. This answer is designed to be a repository for all those questions that have graduated. It is a community wiki answer, so add in your question here, at the end of the list, once it is posted on the main site! Position #1 is an example of how to do this to get the ball rolling.

Sandbox for Proposed Questions
How feasible would it be to "kill" the Sun by using blood?
If the moon was covered in blood, would it achieve the visual effect of deep red moonlight?


Title:
How could a group of Semi-Nomadic subsistence farmers construct a large city?
Setting:

The group lives in an area of ~1.35Million km2
Maximum population around 1 to 1.5 Million people (could be less if needed, but I chose a relatively sparse population density based on Pastoralist communities IRL)
Technological era equivalent to Late-Bronze or Early-Iron age at the LATEST
Environment is Humid Continental climate, mostly forested with grasslands, smaller amount of cold-steppe and desert. Around 40-55o-ish Latitude. Four Seasons.
The group & city functions (mostly) independent from outside groups, and this group were the original builders of the city. Majority/ Entirety of city inhabitants live the following lifestyle:

This group lives primarily as Semi-nomadic farmers, meaning they travel along migratory paths as nomads with herds of animals for around half the year, and return to a defined location (the city) where they practice subsistence farming for the remaining half. (Typically Spring/Summer for farming and Fall/Winter for nomadic pastoralism).
Main Question
Now for the main concern of the question: They have constructed a city. In real semi-nomadic or subsistence farming communities, settlements are typically limited to small or large villages and towns. Part of the reason being the lack of additional products to sell, and generally smaller focus on markets and economy.
In this scenario, the group has at least 1 (or more) major city-like settlement(s) that the majority of its members return to at least once per year. To differentiate the city from just a "large town", this settlement has some or most of the following:

Residential
Food (Agriculture)
Entertainment/ Public Spaces/ Other Leisure
Hygiene & Sanitation/ other water systems
City Defenses
Healthcare
Education
Fire management/ Laws & law enforcement
Religious service/ structure
Markets & Commerce (!)
Governing body

Problems:
Due to their nature as subsistence farmers and nomads, I have found it difficult to justify where they found the time/ physical & economic resources necessary to construct a large and complex city-like settlement. Typically, one would expect that subsistence farmers could only achieve large-villages at most, and that commercial farming is necessary to progress to cities.
In the above list, I noted "Markets & Commerce" as particularly problematic because subsistence farming and pastoralism doesn't leave much to trade, but at the same time seems necessary to generate enough capital for a city to exist.
How could this group have managed to construct such a settlement WITHOUT having abandoned their lifestyle of subsistence farming & nomadic pastoralism?
Tags:

Civilization, Agriculture, Society (not sure what other tags)

Sandbox Notes:

[Draft 1 scrapped/ edited]


Changed the question to be geared more towards "Justify this feature that I already built" instead of "Is this feature possible?". Looking for notes on whether this question is objective or answerable enough to post on the main site.


Read up on the Fulani People, then adjust your question (if it's still necessary), then we can talk. (And I mean read the whole thing. Large nomadic groups have consequences due to the size of their land requirements.)

The question is fine as a question one may ask themselves in a cosy evening by the fire, but the problem is that anybody who attempts to answer is providing little more than speculation. We do have the remains of a number of mysterious late Neolitic sites which were sort of in the right timeframe just before the birth of civilization, for example Çatalhöyük and Göbekli Tepe in Anatolia or Maidanetske in Ukraine, but we don't really understand how they worked. Or in the case of Göbekli Tepe, even what on Earth it was, because a city it definitely wasn't.

OK, are they productive or parasitic in nature? Parasite growth is inherently limited by the resources of the host - so tell us about what they produce. I realize it's a false split, they could be both or something else like conquerors - please tell us about them - or is that the question, what lifestyle will they need to achieve that perhaps?

Can this biological mechanism cause a psychic, contagious corruption affecting only winged, telepathic beings ("Angels")?
In my fictional world, there are winged, telepathic beings called "angels" who coexist peacefully with humans. These angels are not divine; their abilities and physiology are purely biological. They are identical to humans besides for the ability to fly and telepathy (they are capable of procreating with humans). The weight restrictions on human-sized winged flight are possible due to a heavier-than-earth atmosphere, combined with lower gravity.
A catastrophic event occurs during an excavation or mining operation, physically corrupting the majority of the angel population. My idea is that an ancient angel with a corrupted mind is disinterred, and spreads a "mind virus" between the telepathic angels.
This "mind virus" symptoms mirror portrayals of angelic corruption (the divine kind), although the effect is entirely biological. Specifically, the angels:

Bleed from their eyeballs periodically
Are consumed by mindless rage
Have sunken/sallow skin.

Humans remain unaffected by the event, and a small subset of angels is also spared from (immune to) corruption.
I am seeking some sort of malignity that justifies these symptoms, that can be triggered by some sort of psychic transmission.
I am imagining that the organ/part of the brain responsible for receiving incoming telepathic signals becomes damaged and inflamed by the corrupted signal, causing some sort of targeted growth in the brain. This could justify the bleeding eyeballs, assuming the organ resides in the proximity of the eyeballs. (This is a documented effect of certain cancers. Google it yourself if you really want to know...)
Agression is a documented (and sad) side effect of brain tumors. The growth could apply pressure to the part of the brain that regulates agression, accounting for the rage factor.
Regarding the attack vector of the mind virus, I see it as a malicious data packet sent to the telepathy receiver as some sort of, yes, stack overflow, causing it to overload. (Obviously, minds don't work the same way as computers. The idea is that the "message" is crafted to overload the receiver, causing disregulation.)
Seeing as the mind virus has a biological component, it is reasonable why humans and a subset of angels are immune. humans do not possess this organ at all, and the immune angels have a slightly mutated receiver, that does not respond to the malware the same way.
regarding the sallow/sunken skin, here it gets a little weak. The best I can do is allow the growth to have some sort of effect on blood vessels and the vascular system, causing blood circulation to wreak havoc on skin integrity.
In summary, my question is:
Does the described ailment justify the manifestation of its symptoms?
science-fictionbiologycreature-design

This looked like you’re asking us to brainstorm and build your world for you instead of bringing us a specific worldbuilding problem to solve.

@Escapeddentalpatient. In a post (and in comments) the format you must use are either [tag:tag_name] for Main tags or [meta-tag:tag_name] for meta tags.

Ah, so it's then possible to read the tag descriptions... Right. @JBH

@Chani, questions asking for plausible, realistic, possible, etc. goals are fairly hard. It doesn't help when you're asking for a "plausible" in relation to an entirely fictional and entirely undefined species. Normally "plausible" would expect to use the [tag:science-based] tag, but what does that mean when we have absolutely nothing at all to go on? At this stage and with so few details I would expect this question to be closed as "Too Story-Based" because pretty much anything could be used - you need only write it into your story that way. ... (*Continued*)

... We could help you develop your Angels first. If you wish to do that, please use the [tag:creatue-design] tag. In many ways, this might actually be the easier path concerning this post. Decide first how you want your story to go. In other words, decide as the author what tragedy you with to befall your Angels. Then ask us for help designing your Angels to be susceptible to that tragedy. Of course, depending on how far in you are developing your species, we might ask you to start earlier.

BTW, If you're just brainstorming your story and not actually trying to create a worldbuilding rule (worldbuilding rules are always true regardless any story placed in them), then this question doesn't belong on Main. Per the [help/on-topic], we don't help people write their stories. However, you can visit the Story Tellers Corner chat room. You can ask anything you want there.

@JBH I've tried again. Is this any less storybuilding?

Asking us to generate ideas even ideas for worldbuilding is not permitted on this site. Try building this yourself and ask us a specific question should you encounter a problem you can't solve on your own.

It's better, but although you mention you're looking for help designing your angels, you're still brainstorming for the "event" that triggers this consequence. as @sphennings points out. It's made more difficult that you're apparently looking for a Real World solution to an imaginary problem. Let's take it a step further, though. The difference between off-topic brainstorming and an on-topic request for help is the first is looking for a list of possible solutions from which you'll arbitrarily pick the one you like the most. The latter ... (*Continued*)

... invites us to consider a very specific set of conditions, limitations, and restrictions to help you find that one piece of the puzzle that solves your problem. Let's use your (B) as an example. You don't appear to care what physical effects the "event" will cause so long as some physical effect occurs. That's 90% (at least) of all known human pathogens. Since the [help/dont-ask] prohibits questions that lead to all answers having equal value (brainstorming), the current "condition" leaves too many options. (A) is fine (yea! a contagion vs. that ... (*Continued*)

... original list of multiple things. Specific is good!). (C) is a given. There are whomping few pathogens to which no one is immune. The fact of an active immune system all but guarantees that some group is immune - so that's entirely believable. (And please remember, our focus is suspension of disbelief, not scientific veracity. Hopefully it makes sense that nobody can come up with a disease that will affect humans who have wings since there are no humans who have wings. :-) ) So, how do we narrow this down ... (*Continued*)

... so it's not brainstorming? Tell us specifically what physical effects you want/need. Having told us your Angels are humans with wings and psionic abilities we can ignore the wings and psionics and focus on contagions that cause the effects that you have already decided on. Thus, you've resolved the story issues and all that's left is the worldbuilding issue, which must be true regardless of any story set in the world. That requirement would be true in that case. At that point your story would need to introduce a variant of ... (*Continued*)

... "disease X" that deals with the effects of the wings and psionics as narrative necessity requires. That was a long response. Thanks for reading through it! It's worth noting that SE expects research on your part. However, [worldbuilding.se] embraces a remarkably wide array of knowledgeable fields. So unless we feel like the research is a google-search way, you're OK. If we're doing our job (less than I'd like), we'd tell you how we found the proposed solution so you know how to do the research in the future.

@JBH that explanation was epic. I've given the problem some more thought, and I've reflected that into the question. I'm not too confident that my solution makes sense though.

Makes sense is incredibly subjective. Makes sense to whom? Are they suspending belief or are they looking for issues? How much relevant knowledge do they have? Can you ask a more objective question than review my idea? What specifically are you concerned about? We’re not here to review your world or share our opinions with you.

Hmmm... we have an opportunity. As mentioned before, asking us to identify a disease that would effect the telepathy and wings of an otherwise human creature won't work. But your edit is moving the question closer to a form of question we've only just embraced: the [tag:review-my-idea] question. You would need to edit your question further as that tag has very specific rules (read the wiki carefully), but you're moving away from the "what tragic event could..." question toward the "here's my idea, what do you think?" Is that what you want to do?
